# AngularJS - Format Object Key to Month to Display each Month Chronologically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to format an object key to month and display it chronologically by month. Not quite sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'english' | date: 'MMMM' ">
     <h1><strong>{{ month.english }}</strong></h1>
     <p><strong>French Word: </strong>{{ month.french }}</p>
     <p><strong>Number of Days: </strong>{{ month.days }}</p>
     <hr />
</div>
```

Here is a sample of the object:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        var months = [
            {
                english: 'August',
                french: 'Aout',
                days: 31,
                ordinal: 8,
                season: 'summer'
            },
            {
                english: 'March',
                french: 'Mars',
                days: 31,
                ordinal: 3,
                season: 'spring'
            },
            {
                english: 'February',
                french: 'Fevrier',
                days: 28,
                ordinal: 2,
                season: 'winter'
            }
        ];
        $scope.months = months;
    });
```

As of now, it is sorting by alphabet and not the month. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the date filter is incorrect. The only input the date filter accepts is either a Date object, a timestamp, or an ISO 8601 datetime string.

See the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

To order chronologically, why not order by the ordinal, since you already have that data?

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy: 'ordinal'">
```

Comment: Thanks so much Anid. How did it know to sort it by the month without having to refer to 'english'?

Comment: Because the name of the month doesn't matter. `ordinal` is the number of the month, so that's what you want to order by. 1 is January, 2 is February, etc.

Comment: Oh OK got it! Thanks again for helping me with this you are a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to sort it by month number, not name. Use `orderBy: 'ordinal'` instead of `orderBy: 'english'`